# Exif in React native using swift

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, mobile

I am trying to write exif in native way in react native in ios this fuction is called from react native and it is also called and return me the file saved url too. I have checked all the print statement i can see the exif **print("exif metadata", metadata)** written in this line but when I check from react native I cant see any exif written but checking exif in android image is working. Can you please help by seeing this code wheather it is correct or not

```
func writeExifData(_ filePath: String, comment: String, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    guard let imageURL = URL(string: filePath) else {
        reject("Error Invalid_File_Path", "Invalid file path provided", nil)
        return
    }
 
    print("exif imageURL", imageURL)
 
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL as CFURL, nil) else {
        reject("Error Image_Source_Failure", "Failed to create image source", nil)
        return
    }
    print("exif imageSource", imageSource)
 
    guard let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(imageURL as CFURL, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil) else {
        reject("Error Image_Destination_Failure", "Failed to create image destination", nil)
        return
    }
    print("exif imageDestination", imageDestination)
 
    guard let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as? [CFString: Any] else {
        reject("Error Image_Properties_Failure", "Failed to retrieve image properties", nil)
        return
    }
 
    print("exif imageProperties", imageProperties)
 
    var metadata = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] as? [CFString: Any] ?? [CFString: Any]()
    metadata[kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment] = comment
 
    print("exif metadata", metadata)
  ``print("exif metaData userComment", metadata[kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment] ?? "no metadata")
 
    guard let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) else {
        reject("Error Image_Creation_Failure", "Failed to create image", nil)
        return
    }
 
    print("exif metadata", image)
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, image, metadata as CFDictionary)
 
    if CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination) {
        // Retrieve the absolute string representation of the imageURL
        let fileLocation = imageURL.path
        print(fileLocation, "Exif location")
        resolve(fileLocation)
    } else {
        reject("Error: Image_Save_Failure", "Failed to save image with updated EXIF data", nil)
    }
}
```

I am expecting to write exif and upload to s3 in react native I have written native modules for android and also tried in ios but not working in ios. Thanks in Advance

For Kind Notes: I dont know swift or objective C